# What will be the complexity of for loop if nothing is happening in the body of loop

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

**Code:**

```
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    c = i * j;
                }
            }
```

**Time Complexity:** O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Now what will be the complexity of following code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    //c = i * j;
                    // nothing is happening inside the loop
                }
            }
```

whether complexity will be same as above( O(n<sup>2</sup>) ) or something else??

Comment: Your code (even the first version) will be O(1) (constant time). You don't have any variable factor: you always will do 100^2 iterations.

Comment: edited hard coded loop iteration to 'n'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theoretically - yes because there is still the issue of increasing the `i` and `j` which still needs to happen, and comparing them to the end value in each iteration.

However - compilers might optimize it to be done in constant time, and just set the post values of `i` and `j`.

Comment: +1, well put. But since the questioner is talking about big-O, constant time *is* O(n^2)! So optimization doesn't change that the run time is O(n^2), but it might provide a better bound.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You refer to the issue of hard coded "n" I assume. I agree of course - I just tried to answer what the OP is really meaning behind the question.

Comment: No, variable `n`. I just mean that the questioner is slightly misusing big-O notation in saying "will complexity be O(n^2) or something different". Any function that is O(1) is O(n^2), by definition of big-O. So it's O(n^2) *and* something different. I think that's a more important misunderstanding on the questioner's part, I can overlook using `100` where he means a variable quantity :-)

Comment: I think i have to revised the "Growth of the function"!!

Answer (score 1):

For both complexity is O(N^2).